Which rector rules are mandatory when upgrading from PHP 7.4 to 8.x to avoid E_NOTICE, E_WARNING, E_DEPRECATED and E_ERROR?
There is a total of 39 rules in rector to upgrade to PHP 8.0 (21), 8.1 (9), 8.2 (4), 8.3 (4), 8.4 (1).
Which ones are mandatory when upgrading from PHP 7.4 to avoid E_NOTICE, E_WARNING, E_DEPRECATED and E_ERROR and which ones are optional?
https://getrector.com/find-rule
Thanks

this is not a complete response, since rector rules depends on the framework used. If you gave more informations about your codebase, this could be more precisely targeted.
At minima, you should want, for PHP 8.3 target:
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        SetList::DEAD_CODE,
        LevelSetList::UP_TO_PHP_83,
        PHPUnitSetList::PHPUNIT_100,
        PHPUnitSetList::PHPUNIT_CODE_QUALITY,
        PHPUnitSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
    ]);

For a Symfony 6.4 project, I used:
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        SetList::DEAD_CODE,
        LevelSetList::UP_TO_PHP_83,
        DoctrineSetList::DOCTRINE_CODE_QUALITY,
        DoctrineSetList::DOCTRINE_ORM_214,
        DoctrineSetList::DOCTRINE_DBAL_30,
        DoctrineSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        DoctrineSetList::GEDMO_ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        DoctrineSetList::MONGODB__ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        SymfonySetList::CONFIGS,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_64,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CODE_QUALITY,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CONSTRUCTOR_INJECTION,
        SymfonySetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        TwigSetList::TWIG_240,
        TwigSetList::TWIG_UNDERSCORE_TO_NAMESPACE,
        PHPUnitSetList::PHPUNIT_100,
        PHPUnitSetList::PHPUNIT_CODE_QUALITY,
        PHPUnitSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
    ]);


That was the point of my question: Many rules in those sets are not mandatory to avoid E_NOTICE, E_WARNING, E_DEPRECATED and E_ERROR (e.g. SimplifyUselessVariableRector in DEAD_CODE). I'm looking for mandatory ones.

I would go with LevelSetList::UP_TO_PHP_83. If you want something more specific, I recommend setting up PHPstan and identifying the issues one by one.
